# I read website translation phrases from an XML file, is this cached?

Tags: php, xml, caching

I store all my website translation phrases in an XML file, which I read in using PHP on the top of every page.

Is this XML cached in some way? Or is the file read from the server every time I reload a new page? In that case, is this bad for performance?
Would it be better to store all the translation phrases in PHP variables in a PHP file which is included on the top of every page?

Code as requested in comment is below.

On top of every page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include 'lib/phrases.php'; ?>
<?php $phrs = new Phrases(); ?>
```

phrases.php:

```
<?php
class Phrases{

    //load phrases to PHP:
    public function load_phrases($lang_id) {
        $xml = new DomDocument('1.0');

        //path to language directory
        $lang_path=("phrases/".$lang_id.'.xml');
        $xml->load($lang_path);

        //phrases are inside page tags, first we must get these
        $page = $xml->getElementsByTagName('page');
        $page_num=$page->length;

        for($i = 0; $i < $page_num; $i++) {
            $page=$xml->getElementsByTagName('page')->item($i);

            //get phrase tags and store them into array
            foreach($page->getElementsByTagName('phrase') as $phrase) {
                $phrase_name = $phrase->getAttribute('name');
                $phrases[$phrase_name] = $phrase->firstChild->nodeValue;
                $phrases[$phrase_name] = str_replace('\n','<br/>',$phrases[$phrase_name]);
            }
        }

        $this->phrases=$phrases;
    }

    //phrases are accessed
    public function lang_id() {
        //determine page language
        $lang = 'en';
        switch(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2)){
            case 'sv':
                $lang = 'sv';
                break;
            case 'fr':
                $lang = 'fr';
                break;
            case 'it':
                $lang = 'it';
                break;
            case 'no':
                $lang = 'no';
                break;
            default:
                $lang = 'en';
        }

        $lang_id = isset($_COOKIE['lang']) ? $_COOKIE['lang'] : $lang;

        //set the language cookie and update cookie expiration date
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
          $expiration_date=time()+3600*24*7;
          setcookie('lang',$lang_id,$expiration_date,'/');
        }
        if(!isset($lang_id) || $lang_id == NULL) $lang_id = 'en';
        return $lang_id;
    }

    public function change_lang($lang_id) {
         setcookie('lang',$lang_id,$expiration_date,'/');  
    }

    //construct function
    public function __construct() {
      $this->load_phrases($this->lang_id());
    }

}
?>
```

Beginning of XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<language name="en">

    <page name="header">
        <phrase name="header_home">Home</phrase>
        <phrase name="header_blogs">Blogs</phrase>
        <phrase name="header_readmore">Read More</phrase>
```

Comment: What is your php code ?

Comment: If the code (or whatever reader is being used) does not cache, then no: it's not being cached at the application level. Is it a 'slow' operation? Does it affect the site performance? Would it benefit from caching (and what sort)?